# no global web.xml found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I tried to use tomcat 8 embedded for my application but i got this error:

> Nov 21, 2017 11:37:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
> setPath
>
> WARNUNG: A context path must either be an empty string or
> start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet
> these criteria and has been changed to [] configuring app with
> basedir:
> C:\Users\hzammel\Downloads\boualiali-gestion_stock_mvc-086417808484\boualiali-gestion_stock_mvc-086417808484.\src\main\webapp
> Nov 21, 2017 11:37:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>
> INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Nov 21,
> 2017 11:37:19 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool
> getSharedSelector
>
> INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet
> write/read Nov 21, 2017 11:37:19 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>
> INFORMATION:
> Starting service Tomcat Nov 21, 2017 11:37:19 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>
> INFORMATION:
> Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 Nov 21, 2017 11:37:19 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
>
> INFORMATION: No global web.xml found Nov 21, 2017 11:37:21 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFORMATION: No Spring
> WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath Nov 21, 2017
> 11:37:21 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>
> INFORMATION:
> At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
> debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
> scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
> scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. Nov 21,
> 2017 11:37:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>
> INFORMATION: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

this is my class Main :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException,
         InterruptedException, ServletException {

             String docBase = "src/main/webapp/";

              Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
              String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
                    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
                        webPort = "8080";
                    }
                    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
                    
                    StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(docBase).getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + docBase).getAbsolutePath());

                   
                    File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
                    WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
                    resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
                    ctx.setResources(resources);
                     

                    
            /*        
             tomcat.addWebapp("", new File(docBase).getAbsolutePath());
               System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + docBase).getAbsolutePath());
*/
              tomcat.start();
              tomcat.getServer().await();
```

### my folders ##:

src

----------main

```
    ---------- webapp

                      ----------WEB-INF

                                ----------web.xml
```

any help please ??

Comment: Your stack trace is unreadable in this format

Comment: this is the error :Nov 21, 2017 11:37:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFORMATION: No global web.xml found

Answer (score 2):

INFORMATION: No global web.xml found

There is no error here, the logging level here is INFO and Not ERROR. The application should run okay. Check the URL you are typing in the browser to the one that is contained/configured in your project.

Answer (score 0):

We got this message after adding some (xml-) dependencies (jars) in the war file, e. g. xml-apis-*.jar etc., "Starting Servlet Engine" took more than 15 minutes after that. Removing these (unneeded) dependencies avoided the problem.